# All natural numbers of the form $n=2 \cdot S(n)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S(n)$ denote the sum of the digits of a natural number n. Then find all the natural numbers which satisfy the relation

$n=2\cdot S(n)^2$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $n$ has to be twice a square. Second, $n$ can't be too large (It has to be below, say, $2000$). That limits it to about thirty possibilities. That's few enough to just check, one by one.

Comment: It is below $1000$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Levent I think so too, but I wasn't _completely_ certain, since $2S(999)^2>999$.

Comment: Anyway, I just checked all integers between $1$ and $100000$ :) At least we are sure that it is below $100000$.

Answer (score 1):

Using a very simple python code and the argument of @Arthur , there are only $4$ integers satisfying the condition which are $50,162,392,648$.